# ActivatedRoute data doesn't change on same url navigation with different query params

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, ionic4, resolve

I'm trying to implement a filter and once the user submits the filter form, I pass the contents of the form as query params and resolver makes a service call to get the new content based on the filter criteria.

This is how I have setup my route (ReferralsPage is a Lazily Loaded component)

```
//app-routing.module.ts
    {
        path: 'home',
        resolve: {
          loggedIn: AuthenticationResolver
        },
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'referrals', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'referrals', loadChildren: './pages/referrals/referrals.module#ReferralsPageModule' }]
    }

//referralsPageModule.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ReferralsPage,
        resolve: {
          response: ReferralsResolver
        },
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
      }
    ];
```

And the *routes* is passed in the `forChild()` method of RouterModule imported in *ReferralsPageModule*.

This is the `resolve()` function in my `ReferralsResolver`

```
resolve(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ReferralSearchResponse> {
    const criteria = this._getFilterCriteria(snapshot);
    const sort = (criteria && criteria.sort) ? criteria.sort : '-lastUpdated';
    return this._referralsService.getReferrals(1, 25, sort, criteria)
        .pipe(tap(console.log))
  }
```

And, finally, this is the subscription to the activated route data in my Component.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.data.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    })
}
```

This is how I use `router.navigate()` to stay in the page with different `queryParams`.

```
this._router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute, queryParams: this.filterCriteria })
```

My issue is that the *activatedRouteData* *subscription* gets the resolved *data* the **first** time. However, once I apply the filters and *change* the *queryParams*, my resolver runs and fetches data from the server. However, the *activatedRouteData* *subscription* never receives any new data.

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution, you can force the component to reload like this inside your constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Comment: I believe I came across an old answer of yours and I had tried that earlier. It did not work. I tried it again. Didn't work. It's weird because resolver fires and I can see the new data in a tap() function immediately after my rest calls. However, activatedRoute.data stream never gets new data.

Comment: Apologies, Fateh. I forgot to add Ionic4 tag to the question. It seems like an Ionic bug. I started a new Angular application. Added all the boilerplate stuff including onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' to the project with lazily loaded modules and it worked fine. I got new resolved data in my activatedRoute.data stream every time I triggered a same page reload. However, this doesn't seem to work in Ionic 4. If you are versed in Ionic4, I'd ask you to start new Tabs starter template from Ionic. It comes with lazy loaded modules so less setup.